# Invalid character while parse JSON

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I have stored an object in local storage but I got an error while parse that value. I don't know what am missed. I couldn't change the values because of it comes from database. I need a proper way to handle this error instead of changing the string value.

```js
Console.log(JSON.parse("{\"Id\":1,\"MenuType\":\"A00\",\"MenuName\":\"Search\",\"UserDetail\":{\"UserName\":\"rajendranra\"},\"cocFunctions\":[{\"Id\":1,\"FunctionName\":\"View COC\",\"Description\":\"View COC information for a version\",\"IsDefault\":true},{\"Id\":3,\"FunctionName\":\"View order by FYON\",\"Description\":\"View order by FYON\",\"IsDefault\":true},{\"Id\":5,\"FunctionName\":\"Delete COC\",\"Description\":\"Delete existing COC\",\"IsDefault\":false},{\"Id\":7,\"FunctionName\":\"Set and remove COC duplicate\",\"Description\":\"Set and remove COC duplicate\",\"IsDefault\":false},{\"Id\":11,\"FunctionName\":\"Handle COC information for a current version\",\"Description\":\"Handle COC information for a current version\",\"IsDefault\":false},{\"Id\":12,\"FunctionName\":\"Simulate COC\",\"Description\":\"Simulate COC\",\"IsDefault\":false},{\"Id\":15,\"FunctionName\":\"Release or Hold COC\",\"Description\":\"Release or Hold COC\",\"IsDefault\":false},{\"Id\":20,\"FunctionName\":\"Create vehicle on temporary Stop/ FYON\",\"Description\":\"Create vehicle on temporary Stop/ FYON\",\"IsDefault\":false}]}")
```

Comment: what is the error?? the code seems fine after editing it..

Comment: When I try to parse the provided example, I see no error. Are you sure this is the correct example?

Comment: No error here except a missing closing bracket at the end.

Comment: Error is:, Invalid charactera

Comment: @RameshRajendran not in this example. The JSON is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two open parentheses in `Console.log(JSON.parse(` but at the end of the line, you only have one closing parenthesis `)`. You need to add another one.

Additionally, you are capitalizing `Console`. That won't work. It should be `console`.

Answer (score 1):

> `)` is missed at end..!

```js
console.log(JSON.parse("{\"Id\":1,\"MenuType\":\"A00\",\"MenuName\":\"Search\",\"UserDetail\":{\"UserName\":\"rajendranra\"},\"cocFunctions\":[{\"Id\":1,\"FunctionName\":\"View COC\",\"Description\":\"View COC information for a version\",\"IsDefault\":true},{\"Id\":3,\"FunctionName\":\"View order by FYON\",\"Description\":\"View order by FYON\",\"IsDefault\":true},{\"Id\":5,\"FunctionName\":\"Delete COC\",\"Description\":\"Delete existing COC\",\"IsDefault\":false},{\"Id\":7,\"FunctionName\":\"Set and remove COC duplicate\",\"Description\":\"Set and remove COC duplicate\",\"IsDefault\":false},{\"Id\":11,\"FunctionName\":\"Handle COC information for a current version\",\"Description\":\"Handle COC information for a current version\",\"IsDefault\":false},{\"Id\":12,\"FunctionName\":\"Simulate COC\",\"Description\":\"Simulate COC\",\"IsDefault\":false},{\"Id\":15,\"FunctionName\":\"Release or Hold COC\",\"Description\":\"Release or Hold COC\",\"IsDefault\":false},{\"Id\":20,\"FunctionName\":\"Create vehicle on temporary Stop/ FYON\",\"Description\":\"Create vehicle on temporary Stop/ FYON\",\"IsDefault\":false}]}"));
```